# At what stage should we set the value of a significance level? And in what range?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, p-value

There are at least three different recommendations regarding the location of the stage at which we should set the value of the significance level in the hypothesis testing procedure.

1. In [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_hypothesis_testing#The_testing_process) there is a nice description of the hypothesis testing procedure. It claims that we should set the value of the significance level $\alpha$ after selecting the appropriate test and deriving the null distribution of its statistic.
2. However, [below on the same wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_hypothesis_testing#Definition_of_terms) there is a definition of the significance level which says: "Its value is chosen by the statistician prior to looking at the data or choosing any particular test to be used."

Hence, these two methods contradict each other. Moreover, in practice I saw that people often do the following.

3. They calculate the p-value and only after that they set the significance level. For example, if the p-value turned out to be less than 0.01 then they often set the significance level 0.01 and reject the null hypothesis at this level. If the p-value turned out to be greater than 0.01 then they set the significance level 0.05 and make appropriate inferences.

**So, when (at what stage of the hypothesis testing procedure) should we set the value of a significance level?**

Next, some authors (for example, Casella and Berger "Statistical inference" definition 8.3.6 on p.385) wrote that the significance level $\alpha \in [0,1]$ by definition. But many other authors say that the significance level $\alpha \in (0,1)$.
**What is the correct range for possible $\alpha$ values:  $[0,1]$ or $(0,1)$?**

---

Below there are some of my thoughts about these questions (I am not sure that they are correct).

My guess is that in the Neyman–Pearson approach to hypothesis testing (*in this classical approach we calculate the boundaries of the critical region instead of calculating the p-value and then see if the value of the test statistic falls into the critical region; we don't calculate the p-value at all*) the aforementioned method 2 is the most appropriate.

But in the most popular approach (involving explicit calculating of the p-value) I guess that we can use any of the aforementioned methods 1, 2, 3.

On the second question, I tend to agree with Casella-Berger, however I have never seen usage of $\alpha = 0$ or $\alpha = 1$.

Comment: I see no contradiction, because there is no mention of examining the data until step 8 ("compute from the observations...").  As far as possible values of $\alpha$ go, it is extremely rare (even among mathematical examples) for values of $\alpha=0$ or $\alpha=1$ to result in any kind of meaningful test: think about what such choices of $\alpha$ might mean.

Comment: @whuber In method 1 we should choose the appropriate test before setting the significance level and method 2 insists that we should choose the appropriate test after setting the significance level (why it insists on that?) Also step 3 of method 1 talks about setting the assumptions. I think in practice people often set the assumptions "about the form of the distributions of the observations" (i.e. the family of the allowed distributions, symmetry of the distribution, etc.) after they looked at the data. Sometimes on step 3 normality tests are done to see if the samples are normally distributed

Comment: It is fair to question the order in which $\alpha$ is selected and a test is chosen, because in practice this process is iterative.  Often the client wants an impracticably small value of $\alpha.$  When they see how much it would cost (in sampling budget and time) to achieve that level, compromises are made requiring a trade-off between test size and power.  Part of that process can (perhaps often) does involve selecting a different test.  Thus, stipulating $\alpha$ and choosing the test are intertwined rather than being strictly sequential.

Comment: The issues of selecting tests based on preliminary examinations of the data and performing normality testing are fraught: you can find many discussions of them here on CV.  Suffice it to say that without proper care, such procedures result in overly optimistic (low) p-values.  This isn't to say such things aren't done: this kind of data-snooping is likely the norm rather than the exception.

Comment: depends on the objectives of your study - exploratory, experimental or confirmatory and many more issues - resources , urgency etc.